# Detect existence of private member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-traits

I want to write a type trait to check if some type has a member `member`. If `member` were *public*, there are any number of ways to do this (e.g. [`void_t`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911.pdf)), the most concise of which is probably [Yakk's `can_apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29521342/2069064) (which could eventually be called [`std::is_detected`](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf)):

```
struct C {
    int member;
};

template <typename T>
using member_type = decltype(&T::member);

template <typename T>
using has_member = can_apply<member_type, T>;

static_assert(has_member<C>{}, "!"); // OK
```

But if the member were *private*, this trait fails, since the access on `member` is ill-formed (we are not friends) and there is no differentiation between ill-formed due to access reasons and ill-formed due to this-thing-doesn't-exist reasons:

```
class D {
    int member;
};

static_assert(has_member<D>{}, "!"); // error
```

Is there a way to write such a member checker across all access controls?

Comment: Not trying to say this is a bad idea. I'm not qualified to do so. But I am genuinely curious, what would be the use of this? I.e., what's the use case of querying `private` characteristics of a type (which you couldn't access anyhow)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/possible-for-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence#264088

Comment: If `member` is private, you should be able to safely rename that member without breaking external code that merely happens to be using your class. Being able to create a `has_member` template the way you're using would make it *very* easy to create code that at the very least does not act the way another developer might reasonably expect code to act. So I share DevSolar's question: what use do you have for this?

Comment: @DevSolar I was genuinely curious to see if such a thing was possible. Name lookup itself doesn't consider access, so it seems like it should be possible to wrap in a type trait.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is indeed a way for non-final non-union class types:

```
namespace detail {
    struct P {typedef int member;};
    template <typename U>
    struct test_for_member : U, P
    {
        template <typename T=test_for_member, typename = typename T::member>
        static std::false_type test(int);
        static std::true_type test(float);
    };
}
template <typename T>
using test_for_member =
  std::integral_constant<bool, decltype(detail::test_for_member<T>::test(0)){}>;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3c68849d50b8b4c). The trick is to check whether lookup into different base classes will yield an ambiguity. [class.member.lookup]/2:

> Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (*id-expression*)
>   in a class scope (3.3.7). Name lookup can result in an *ambiguity*, in
>   which case the program is ill-formed. […] Name lookup takes place
>   before access control (3.4, Clause 11).

Note that GCCs lookup is broken insofar as it ignores non-type names for lookup in *typename-specifier*s.

Comment: I always found it entirely counterintuitive that lookup was independent of protection. Strange that C++ allows for identifiers which, in certain contexts, are a *complication* without being at all *useful*.

Answer (score 9):

You can create another class `MemberBase` that *does* have that member, and then subclass the two classes (the class to check `T` and `BaseMember`) and try to access the member of the subclass. If `T` also has a `member` member, then you will get an ambiguity problem.

Code:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Yakk's can_apply

template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type {};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply< Z, types<Ts...>, void_t< Z<Ts...> > >:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,types<Ts...>>;

// Main code

class MemberBase {
    public:
        int member;
};

template<class ToCheck>
class MemberCheck: public ToCheck, public MemberBase {
};

template <typename T>
using member_type = decltype(&T::member);

template <typename T>
using hasnot_member = can_apply<member_type, MemberCheck<T>>;

template <typename T> 
using static_not = std::integral_constant<bool, !T::value>;

template <typename T>
using has_member = static_not<hasnot_member<T>>;

// Tests

class A {
    int member;
};

class Ap {
    public:
    int member;
};

class B {
    float member;
};

class C {
    int member();
};

class D {
};

static_assert(has_member<A>{}, "!"); // ok
static_assert(has_member<Ap>{}, "!"); // ok
static_assert(has_member<B>{}, "!"); // ok
static_assert(has_member<C>{}, "!"); // ok
static_assert(has_member<D>{}, "!"); // fail
```

However, this definitely smells like a dirty hack to me.