# Structure specialization when the class has an operator()

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-specialization

I would like to specialize a structure when the passed type has an `operator()` (a functor or a lambda function). For the moment, I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class...>
struct mystruct: std::false_type {};

template <class C> 
struct mystruct<C, decltype(&C::operator())>: std::true_type {};

int main() {
    int n = 42;
    auto lambda = [&n](int i){return i + n;};

    // Should return false: OK
    std::cout<<mystruct<decltype(x)>::value<<std::endl;

    // Should return true: problem
    std::cout<<mystruct<decltype(lambda)>::value<<std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

How to make it work?

Bonus question: how to make it work even when the `operator()` is protected or private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be an appropriate use of the [`void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) technique:

```
template <class, class = std::void_t<>>
struct mystruct: std::false_type {};

template <class C> 
struct mystruct<C, std::void_t<decltype(&C::operator())>>: std::true_type {};
```

Although `void_t` is only in the library since C++17, it is easy to add to your own utility library.

For the bonus question, see [Detect existence of private member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566579/detect-existence-of-private-member).

Comment: Caveat: That breaks for overloaded or templated `operator()`'s.