# Is it ill-formed to attempt to access private member of a class to sfinae out overload?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sfinae, type-traits, private-members

While attempting to create a trait to check whether the class field is publicly available I've created a code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T, class = void>
struct does_not_have_foo: std::true_type {};

template <class T>
struct does_not_have_foo<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().foo, void())>: std::false_type {};

class Foo {
    int foo;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(does_not_have_foo<Foo>::value);
}
```

But it appeared to failed to compile in [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z4qaB6dSpA9aUZfM) ([[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uoq2RMjFGb2qRJUN) seemed to be more permissive here) with an error:

```
prog.cc:8:56: error: 'int Foo::foo' is private within this context
```

I dug up for some older code of mine doing something similar which boils down to following:

```
template <class T>
auto does_not_have_foo(T t) -> decltype(t.foo, std::false_type()) {
    return {};
}

std::true_type does_not_have_foo(...) { return {}; }

class Foo {
    int foo;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(decltype(does_not_have_foo(Foo{}))::value);
}
```

It looked like it done its job in both [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o4FMesUKP9RGyzuW) just as well as in [[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BeWUKX95tCMeiLr3). But when I was looking for a reason of gcc failure I found the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566579/detect-existence-of-private-member) which suggests that every attempt to use of private field of the class is ill-formed and as such even the second code should be avoided. Am I over-interpreting the question or is the second code really the language abuse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But it appeared to failed to compile in [gcc] ([clang] seemed to be more permissive here)

It's actually gcc that's more permissive here. [gcc bug 59002](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59002) is a meta-bug that captures the many bugs that gcc has when it comes to access control and templates. To gcc, in your first scenario, accessing `Foo::foo` is fine, even though it's private. In your second, slightly different scenario, gcc correctly rejects the private access.

`does_not_have_foo` is correctly implemented in the first scenario, clang compiles it correctly. It's just that gcc incorrectly implements access checking. The second implementation is equally correct.